No detecto el error en el código: "odbc_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource"
Tengo este Codigo:
  if (!$conn = @odbc_connect("Driver={SQL Server};Server=127.0.0.1;", 'Clasic20dddeUser', 'ClasiPass'))
    die ("Couln't connect to Database.");
$BLOG = $conn;
//print_r($BLOG);
$UserUID ='2393';
$consulta = odbc_prepare  ($BLOG, "SELECT TOP 1 UserUID FROM PS_UserData.dbo.Users_Master WHERE UserUID = ?");
$rest = odbc_execute ($consulta, array($UserUID));
$re = odbc_fetch_array($rest);
// echo $re['UserUID'];
echo'Aqui el resultado ('.$re['UserUID'].')';

Me da el siguiente error:
odbc_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\onex.php on line #


El error dice: odbc_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given 
Es decir, que está dándole a la funcion un boolean, cuando se está esperando un resource.
Estás intentando hacer $re = odbc_fetch_array($rest);
Y el error te dice que $rest, es un booleano, es decir, true o false.
Al analizar $rest, podemos ver que intentas hacer:
$rest = odbc_execute($consulta, array($UserUID));

La función odbc_execute retorna true en caso de éxito, y false en caso de error -> https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.odbc-execute.php
Lo que tu buscas hacer, es lo siguiente:
//Preparar la consulta
$consulta = odbc_prepare($BLOG, "SELECT TOP 1 UserUID FROM PS_UserData.dbo.Users_Master WHERE UserUID = ?");

//Ejecutar la consulta
if (!odbc_execute($consulta, array($UserUID))) {
    die("Error en el execute de la query: " . odbc_errormsg($BLOG));
}

//Obtener los resultados
$re = odbc_fetch_array($consulta);

Como ves, los resultados los obtenemos de $consulta directamente, no de la función obdc_execute()

El error se debe a una confusión sobre lo que retorna la función odbc_execute(). Como bien lo mensiona Excorpion en su respuesta, esta retorna un valor booleano (true o false) indicando si la ejecución fue exitosa, pero no retorna un conjunto de resultados.
Para obtener los resultados, debes usar la consulta preparada directamente con funciones como odbc_fetch_array().
Te doy este ejemplo paso a paso y comentado con los conceptos principal de la implementacion de odbc_:
<?php
// Establecer conexión con la base de datos
$dsn = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=127.0.0.1;Database=PS_UserData;"; // Especificar la base de datos si es necesario
$user = 'Clasic20dddeUser';
$password = 'ClasiPass';

// Intentar conectar
$conn = @odbc_connect($dsn, $user, $password);

if (!$conn) {
    die("Error al conectar a la base de datos: " . odbc_errormsg());
}

// Definir la variable a buscar
$UserUID = '2393';

// Preparar la consulta SQL
$query = "SELECT TOP 1 UserUID FROM PS_UserData.dbo.Users_Master WHERE UserUID = ?";
$consulta = odbc_prepare($conn, $query);

if (!$consulta) {
    die("Error al preparar la consulta: " . odbc_errormsg($conn));
}

// Ejecutar la consulta con los parámetros
if (!odbc_execute($consulta, array($UserUID))) {
    die("Error al ejecutar la consulta: " . odbc_errormsg($conn));
}

// Recuperar los resultados
$re = odbc_fetch_array($consulta);

if ($re) {
    echo 'Aquí el resultado: (' . $re['UserUID'] . ')';
} else {
    echo "No se encontraron resultados para UserUID: $UserUID.";
}

// Cerrar la conexión
odbc_close($conn);

Utiliza estas referencias:

odbc_connect:
https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.odbc-connect.php
odbc_prepare:
https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.odbc-prepare.php
odbc_execute:
https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.odbc-execute.php
odbc_fetch_array:
https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.odbc-fetch-array.php

ten en consideración que cada apartado de la documentacion tiene una especifica llamada "Valores devueltos"
